# querying in MYSQL according to row number

Tags: mysql, database

If there is a way to query according to row number ? Like:

```
select rownumber from table;
```

**what i am trying to do:**
I have computed the total number of rows in a table using sub queries and now I want to display only the last one.

**rookie answer:**

I wanted to get the 2nd highest salary. so this is what i did:

```
select * from gg where salary< (select max(salary) from gg) order by salary desc limit 1
```

This doesnot work for Nth highest salary its for 2nd highest only. AND I AM NEW TO THIS SO I JUST WANTED TO GET THE 2ND HIGHEST BY MY OWN METHOD.

Comment: u mean "select Count(*) from table?"

Comment: what actually you want??? you want to view records in the increasing  or decreasing order of rownumber? or you will provide one rownumber and you want to get that row???

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is available only in Sql Server not avail in MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure why you would want to get a specific rownumer, you could do it like this:

```
select * from table LIMIT rownumer, 1;
```

Read more on this on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

So if you want the 3rd row you'll do:
`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3,1;`

If you want the 6th-16th row you'll use:
`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 6,10`

Do understand that this is only usefull to get a random row or when you add SORT BY. Otherwise you will never be sure what row will be returned...

Comment: @CraigRinger: Really, why would this work? This is just a normal SQL query. But I will add a link to the MySQL SELECT manual...

Comment: It is okay to have OP do some research of his own.

Comment: @Nin I don't think the poster's question was about a table column named `rownumber`; rather they seem to want something like SQL Server's `ROW_NUMBER` or the `row_number()` window function in standard SQL.

Comment: No, he wants 1 records from the table which is on the n-th position. Which is exactly what my answer does. I'll add some more information in the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just limit your query to return only a specific number of rows you can use the Mysql built in `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset` clause. But, If you want to select a ranking number like a row number use:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select *
FROM
(
   Select *,  (@rownum := @rownum+1) as rank
   FROM t
) sub
```

**Update:** If you want to

> I want to display only the last one.

Then you can do it this way:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Yourquery
  ORDER BY SomeField DESC --This how you determine the last one based on the order
  LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select records with row number see this:

```
SELECT (@rank := @rank + 1) AS row_number
        ,contract_id, price1, price2, price3
      FROM t1, (SELECT @rank := 0) tmp;
```

If you want only row number see this:

```
SELECT (@rank := @rank + 1) AS row_number
      FROM t1, (SELECT @rank := 0) tmp
```

## [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3d39/12)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table limit [offset,limit]
```

**offset** is  the row number which you want to start,

**limit** is the count of rows you want to get starting from offset

so you can use it like

```
select * from table limit rownumber,1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no row number without ordering, but if you do have a sort order in mind then

```
SELECT * FROM thing ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 1 OFFSET your_row;
```